# Javascript toString() strange behavior

Tags: javascript, tostring, number-formatting

I have a really strange output result from toString() built in function

Here is my code:

```
function strangeFunction(num)
{
return num.toString();
}


alert( strangeFunction(121.112*100) ); //output: 12111.199999999999 
alert( strangeFunction(.1*100) );  //output: 10 
alert( strangeFunction(1.33*100) ); //output: 133
alert( strangeFunction(133.33*100) ); //output: 13333.000000000002 
alert( strangeFunction(133.33*100) );//output: 13334
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sVMf4/

Any suggestions how to fix that issue? It seems that ther is some kind of bug or number formatting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not JavaScript only, virtually every language manipulating [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) value have this issue.

To avoid it, you can use `Math.round()` or `.toFixed()`.

```
Math.round(123.456);
// returns 123

123.4.toFixed(2);
// returns "123.40"
```

There is also `.toPrecision()` but it may decide to use scientific notation (like `1.2e+2`) which is often not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function numToStr(var number, var dec) {
    return number.toFixed(dec);
}

var number = 121.112*100;

alert(numToStr(number , 0));
```

Output:

```
12111
```

**toFixed()** lets you to convert a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's an old javascript issue:

[How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

Another possible solution:

```
function strangeFunction(num)
{
    num = Math.round(num); 
    return num.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the way floating point numbers are saved internally.
You can try this if you are sure about the precision you want.

```
function strangeFunction(num)
{
    return parseFloat(num.toPrecision(12)).toString();
}
```